# Why are the icons not displaying in a DT::datatable in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, sparklines

I'm having some trouble displaying icons with sparklines within a `DT::datatable` column in a Shiny app even though I have escaped the HTML.

Edit: Removed 2nd question.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  htmlwidgets::getDependency('sparkline'),

  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    raw_data <- data.frame(date = 2000:2021,
                     value = sample(100:500, 22),
                     icon = as.character(icon("arrow-up")))

  data <- raw_data %>%
    group_by(icon) %>%
    # Create the sparkline
    summarise("value" = sparkline::spk_chr(c(value),
                                xvalues = date,
                                tooltipFormat = '{{x}}: {{y}}'))

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    cb <- htmlwidgets::JS('function(){debugger;HTMLWidgets.staticRender();}')

    DT::datatable(data = data,
              escape = FALSE,
              options = list(drawCallback = cb))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not ask two questions in the same post. The rule is one question per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `shiny::icon` function:

1. generates the HTML code corresponding to the icon;
2. *generates a script tag which includes the **font-awesome** icon library*.

When you do `as.character(icon(......`, you only get the HTML code. The **font-awesome** library is not loaded, that's why the icon does not display.

The simplest way to get the icon is to use the **glyphicon** icon library, which is included in **bootstrap** so there's nothing to load (since **bootstrap** is loaded in Shiny apps):

```
as.character(icon("arrow-up", lib = "glyphicon"))
```

If you really want a **font-awesome** icon, there are two possibilities:

- include the **font-awesome** library with a `link` tag;
- or use the `icon` function elsewhere in your app, without `as.character` (you can hide it with the `display:none` CSS property if you don't want to see this icon) as shown below.

```r
# add inside ui
tags$span(icon("tag"), style = "display: none;")
```

Comment: any chance you may have some suggestions in regards of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100688/r-shiny-table-with-sparkline-boxplot ? Thank you